# Deleting and Adding records to list using a SP timer job

Tags: 2013

I have a requirement to create a timer job . The timer job should delete 250000 records daily and add another 270000 records daily . I find the timer job code written on server side is taking lot of time to execute (3-4 hrs)

What is the best solution for something like this , i want the execution to be taking not more than 30 min .

Comment: SharePoint likely isn't the best solution for this. What is the intended purpose of this application? Remember that you have to instantiate an entire class (SPItem) -- I'd suggest just doing this a non-SharePoint SQL database and perhaps surface that content to SharePoint (BCS? SSRS? Power BI?).

Comment: I have a feed of these many records which is validated against a custom control .